# Unable to get attribute value using JAXB ( For attribute in Parent class)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to read one xml using JAXB.

I am facing one weird issue where attribute of parent is not being read,but attributes of child classes are read.
I have referenced forums, but this seems to be a strange one.

Can anyone please let me know what is the mistake i am doing.

**XML.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PhoneDirectory>
<Exchange exchangeName="ashfield2133">Ashfield</Exchange>
<PhoneNumber id="23" number="0489524401">
<FirstName>Test</FirstName>
<LastName>Test</LastName>
<Address>#34,rt road, State,Country,22344 </Address>
</PhoneNumber>

<PhoneNumber id="88" number="0409545401">
<FirstName>Testf2</FirstName>
<LastName>Testl2</LastName>
<Address>St 2 , State,Country,34555</Address>
</PhoneNumber>


<PhoneNumber id="88" number="0446775401">
<FirstName>Testf3</FirstName>
<LastName>Testl3</LastName>
<Address>St 3 , State,Country,546777</Address>
</PhoneNumber>

</PhoneDirectory>
```

**PhoneDirectory Class**

```
package com.test.phoneDirectory.dataclass;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;


@XmlRootElement(name="PhoneDirectory")
public class PhoneDirectory {

    private String exchange;
    private String exchangeName;

    @XmlElement(name="Exchange")
    public String getExchange() {
        return exchange;
    }

    public void setExchange(String exchange) {
        this.exchange = exchange;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="exchangeName")
    public String getExchangeName() {
        return exchangeName;
    }

    public void setExchangeName(String exchangename) {
        this.exchangeName = exchangename;
    }

    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumber;

    @XmlElement(name="PhoneNumber")
    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

**PhoneNumber Class**

```
package com.test.phoneDirectory.dataclass;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="PhoneNumber")
public class PhoneNumber {

    private String id;
    private String number;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="number")
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="FirstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="LastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


}
```

**Main class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import com.test.phoneDirectory.dataclass.PhoneDirectory;
import com.test.phoneDirectory.dataclass.PhoneNumber;


public class GetAllPhoneData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(PhoneDirectory.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        PhoneDirectory phoneDirectory = (PhoneDirectory) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("src/config/PhoneDirectory.xml"));


        System.out.println("Get all phone details");
        System.out.println("Exchange:"+phoneDirectory.getExchange());
        System.out.println("exchangeName:"+phoneDirectory.getExchangeName());


      for (PhoneNumber phonedetails : phoneDirectory.getPhoneNumber()) {

          System.out.println(phonedetails.getId());
          System.out.println(phonedetails.getNumber());
          System.out.println(phonedetails.getFirstName());
          System.out.println(phonedetails.getLastName());
          System.out.println(phonedetails.getAddress());
    }

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Get all phone details    
Exchange: Ashfield    
****Get exchangeName :null****    
23    
0489524401    
Test    
Test    
#34,rt road, State,Country,22344
```

As you can see the exchangeName is null despite mentioning XMLAttribute annotation for field.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the `exchangeName` attribute in the `PhoneDirectory` class but your XML has this attribute in the `Exchange` element.

So instead of

```
private String exchange;
private String exchangeName;
```

you'll need a class like `Exchange` with `@XmlAttribute` `exchangeName` and `@XmlValue` `exchange`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for pointing it out. :) Its working now.